# Не могу подключить зависимости в gradle проекте, используя Socks. Как решить данную проблему?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, firebase-android

Всем доброго времени суток. Суть проблемы такая, я пишу небольшое приложение на android, и мне потребовалось подключить к приложению firebase. Я с помощью android studio, и кое какой матери, синхронизировался с firebase, создал тут новый проект с идентичным именем создал и в studio. Далее, я хочу встроить в приложение аутентификацию пользователей. Firebase самостоятельно прописывает свои зависимости в мой build.gradle. Вот что в нём написано:

```
`// 
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'     
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()        
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}`
```

И, после этого, когда я пытаюсь собрать проект, gradle пытается скачать эти зависимости, и это происходит часами...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я также использую подключение через proxy. Я прописал это как в settings андроид студии, так и в gradle.properties. 
При чем в прошлом проекте, я не мог подключить зависимости с репозиториев maven(), вот именно также шло время, а закачивание не происходило. В итоге я получал ошибку : ERROR: Connection timed out: connect. Брэндмаур в windows 7 полностью отключен. Помогите, как мне всё таки заставить эти dependency заработать?

P.S. прилагаю скрин настроек proxy в студии.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 2 вопроса. Покажите свой settings в студии, второй вопрос: вы запускаете родной gradle или gradlew?

Comment: Скрин настроек приложил. Использую gradlew.

Comment: С корня проекта попробуйте с командной строки запустить `gradlew.bat` - что пишет?

Comment: В Event loge висит надпись : 12:43 Executing tasks: [gradlew.bat] in project D:\Prog\android\android poekts\MyReadyProects\Firebase И идет выполнение, но оно не заканчивается

Comment: Возможно есть ещё какие то настройки в gradle, где нужно указать proxy, кроме как gradle.properties в корне проекта? В самой студии я написал. Хотя в таком случае соединение бы вообще не происходило, а тут оно висит. Загрузка файлов не идет.

Comment: У вас прокси точно без логина/пароля? Скорее всего он есть и совпадает с паролем входа в домен. У SOCKS обычно так.

Comment: Да, точно без логина/пароля. В подключении указывается лишь host и port.

Comment: Причем тут такой момент интересный: в Background Tasks, gradle будь то перебирает зависимости, но не загружает их. И этот самый процесс бесконечен.

Comment: кнопка "check connection" в настройках прокси что показывает? Пробовали?

Comment: Да, пробовал. Connection successful. Студия подключается к интернету, я могу ставить плагины, могу её обновить. Также и gradle имеет подключение, так как я создавал несколько проектов, один из них собирал с помощью gradle в offline режиме, другой уже по дефолту. Оба собирались. Но вот как дело дошло до подключения зависимостей, но тут каким то чудом, в tasк висит выполнение задачи и ничего не происходит, нет не закачки, не остановки. Только по истечению времени выводится сообщение в лог : ERROR: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Я также скачал zip - архивы с gradle, несколько последних версий. По очереди устанавливал их, прописывал пути в системных переменных, думал возможно какая то ошибка под капотом gradle, но всё было тщетно. Пустые проекты собирались на ура. Но подключение зависимостей с репозиториев maven(),jcenter(),google() приводило к залипанию

Comment: Попробуйте тогда не через gradle-wrapper, а через gradle - в настройках надо указать на путь к бинарникам gradle - проблема явно не в прокси

Comment: Полночи просидел. Пробовал версии gradle : 5.6.4; 5.5.1; 5.4.1; 5.3; 5.0. Всё также. Gradle собирает проект, затем начинает пытаться подключить зависимости, скачав их, и на этом всё. Ждем около 25-30 минут, выпадает сообщение : ERROR: Connection timed out: connect.